# How Do I Forward Port 80 to Flash Media Server and IIS?

Tags: iis, portforwarding, flash-media-server

FMS and IIS are set up with separate IPs on the same server.  Both are configured for port 80 because others, including 1935, are often inaccessible from certain environments.

Problem is, the server's behind a router.  Port 80 can only be forwarded to either the IP of FMS or that of IIS.

Even if the two were on separate machines, I'd still have to deal with this.  What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

If the router has to external IP addresses you could do this.

If the router only has one external IP address, you will need to use two different external ports, as two things can't listen on the same port.

eg:

- External:80 -> IIS:80
- External:81 -> FMS:80
- (External:80 -> IIS:80 and FMS:80 is impossible)

If you had two external IP addresses (and a router that supported that), you could do:

- External1:80 -> IIS:80
- External2:80 -> FMS:80

Comment: Thanks.  If I use external 81 for my FMS, it will not be accessible from within networks (e.g., corporate) that have 81 blocked.

Comment: You only solution then to get a second external IP address then. Most corporate networks that have firewalls that strict will probably be using HTTP proxy servers to filter traffic,  FMS won't work through a web proxy even if it's running on port 80.

Comment: I'll look into the two IP possibility.

Comment: Twelve, is it correct to assume that if YouTube is accessible in a corporate network, my FMS running on port 80 should be too?